# How to bind event handler to method of specific object?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting, binding

```
<ListView Name="ProductListView" Background="#AAFFFFFF" Margin="10,5,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="product">
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Sort"/> <!-- Sort is method of product object-->
    </Style>
```

"product" is object that have item of list view
and I wrote sort function.
I want to know how to specific the "Sort"
to handler of the Click event..?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may not do that in MVVM!!!

Instead try this tuts out:

http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/filtering-and-sorting-a-wpf-listbox/

Comment: thank you dev hedgehog..
now I can fix it, by C# programmatically add manual, not XAML